# Bootstrap date-picker on change event on text box is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I had a date-picker which was working correctly.And its change event was also working fine. Now i implemented a icon and make text box read-only. Now the change event is not fired neither in read-only textbox case nor in non-read-only textbook case.I have changes only html.

HTML of working case:

```
<label class="control-label">Date</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" id="StateDatePicker" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

Javascript of working case:

```
$StateDatePicker = $("#StateDatePicker");
        $(".date-picker").datetimepicker({


  format: "MM/DD/YYYY"
        })
This is how i called change event.

        $StateDatePicker.on("dp.change", function () {
            //Performing functionality 
        });
```

This was working fine.It was no icon in working case, now i added icon showing in picture:[image]

Now i have changed the following:
HTML:

```
<div class='date-picker input-group date'>
<input type='text' class="form-control" id="StateDatePicker" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Date-picker is working fine, only change event is not called
There is no change in JS. Why its change event is not called is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got my answer
I tried this and it working now

```
<div class='date-picker input-group date'  id="StateDatePicker"> //Set id to div
<input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$("#StateDatePicker").datetimepicker({
    format: "MM/DD/YYYY"
}).on("changeDate", function () {
    //Performing functionality 
});
```

or maybe change your HTML to this: (give id for div tag, not input field)

```
<div class="input-group input-append date" id="StateDatePicker">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
   <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the function you want to do inside change event.? It may help pp to find out what's wrong easier ...

I updated the answer, maybe u can try it ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this where you have placed

This may help you (Not Sure)

```
  <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working demo.
Html Section

```
 <div class="form-group input-group">
            <label class="input-group-btn" for="date-fld1">
                <span class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control date-input" id="date-fld1" readonly/>
 </div>
```

And in script-----------

```
$(".date-input").datepicker().on("changeDate",function(){

alert('hi');

});
```

CDN files used 
- http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
and http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML :

on your javascript :

$('.form_date').datetimepicker({
            language:  'id',
            weekStart: 1,
            todayBtn:  1,
            autoclose: 1,
            todayHighlight: 1,
            startView: 2,
            minView: 2,
            forceParse: 0
        });

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datepicker's onSelect event.

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    display("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
  }
});
```

If you like, of course, you can make the change event on the input fire:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
    $(this).change();
  }
});
```